# How to make charts similar to stripe's dashboard ones

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I am writing to you as I am in confusion now, understanding and trying to learn by cloning amazing designs especially from my favourite website stripe.com. I have tried to create a chart similar to stripe's chart, using React & React-charts, but failed then tried again with visx library ( harder to use ) but failed again. I am turning to you for help, if someone can help understand how to make similar visuals as stripe's.

Thank you,

[stripe's dashboard analytics chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW8oX.jpg)

PS: I tried using React and react charts and visx but failed miserably to create and clone such an amazing visual.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chart.js library.
https://www.chartjs.org/
it has more options compared to React chart.